# How can you do the equivalent of a MINUS in MySQL whilst still using an index?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been looking for ages about how to do a query like this but use an index.

```
SELECT * FROM aliens_tmp 
WHERE creator !=  'a'
AND COUNTRY = 'UK' 
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

Whatever index I create will not get a hit because of the != clashing with the inclusive nature of indexes.

So I thought about doing a minus where I do something like

```
SELECT * FROM aliens_tmp 
WHERE COUNTRY = 'UK 
MINUS
SELECT * FROM aliens_tmp 
WHERE CREATOR = 'a' 
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

...but MINUS doesn't exist. So I looked and figured I could use the old trick mentioned on http://www.bitbybit.dk/carsten/blog/?p=71 which briefly is

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.member_id, a.name
FROM a LEFT JOIN b USING (member_id, name)
WHERE b.member_id IS NULL
```

but that doesn't help me with the original goal of doing a MINUS whilst maintaining the use of an index as any join to my own table still has to **exclude** my creator which causes the miss because of the **exclude** Any ideas?

Comment: What index are you trying to hit? Is it on creator or country or both?

Comment: How many different values creator can have? And how many rows out of total satisfy creator='a' condition?

Comment: @James. I would probably hit some sort of composite index based on the keys being selected

Comment: @piotrm there are currently over 60k creators. Countries have around 20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If most of your table consists of rows with `creator != 'a'` then using index will not give you any advantage. However if you have mostly rows with `creator='a'` then you can consider assigning such values to creator (or using enum) that if you order by creator 'a' would go first. Instead of checking for `creator != 'a'` you could then use `creator > 'a'` condition, which is perfectly fine for using btree indexes.

UPDATE after more info about creator:

So your `creator != 'a'` condition has extremely low selectivity and trying to use index on creator is pointless. You are limiting your results and ordering by id desc, so the key on country should be used to return as few rows as possible by simply checking every single row starting from highest id whether it satisfies where conditions until there are enough for your limit. If you see key: country and number of rows close to 10 in your `explain select ...` it won't get any faster.

Answer (score 0):

The index will not buy you anything in this case, your original query with the `!=` will be your fastest option.

The reason is that to do the MINUS you are talking about, the database would need to retrieve all rows, then check each row against the index to determine if it should be removed.  This requires it to examine every row in the table.

Your original query will also need to examine every row, but will only need to check it for the condition you specified.

This means that your original query would be faster even if there were a `MINUS` operation like you describe.

In fact, your original query may be faster because it only needs to check the condition and would not have to do an index lookup for every row.

Answer (score 0):

An index on creator would probably not be very useful, even it it could be used. !=a would probably return more than half the rows in the table. A table scan is going to be more efficient than using an index in that case. An index on country MIGHT help, assuming there are many countries, but if half your users are in UK, you'd have the same problem there too.

You could consider partitioning your data in to two tables, 'a' creators, and 'not a' creators, if that makes sense for your application.